# QT Quick Test KeyClicks

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to implement a keyClick with a shift modifier but it doesn't work. Below is a basic setup of what I am trying to do. The first test_case1 can perform what I am doing but I'd like the second test_case2 to work as well but with using the Qt.ShiftModifier.

`../MyTextBox.qml`

```
Page {
    id: page1
    objectName: "page1"

    TextField {
        id: lastNameField
        objectName: "lastNameField"
        text: qsTr("")
    }
}
```

`tst_page.qml`

```
import "../"

Item {
    width: 800
    height: 600

    MyTextBox {
        id: page1
    }

    TestCase {
        id: "txtBox"
        when: windowShown

            function test_case1 () {
                //var qmlObj = findChild(page1, "lastNameField")
                var qmlObj = page1.lastNameField
                // Bring to focus
                mouseClick(qmlObj, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier)
                // Keypress
                keyPress("Y")
                keyPress("e")
                keyPress("s")

                tryCompare(qmlObj, "text", "Yes") // pass
            }    

            function test_case2 () {
                var qmlObj = page1.lastNameField
                // Bring to focus
                mouseClick(qmlObj, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier)
                // Keypress
                keyClick(QT.Key_Y, Qt.ShiftModifier)
                keyClick(QT.Key_E)
                keyClick(QT.Key_S)

                tryCompare(qmlObj, "text", "Yes") // fail
            }  
     }         
}
```

`test output`

```
PASS   : test_case1()
FAIL!  : test_case2()
   Actual    (): yes
   Expected  (): Yes
```

Edit: Added a [simple project](https://github.com/iSlayer/my_quick_example) to github for testing.

Comment: change `ShiftModifier` with `Qt.Key_CapsLock`

Comment: I tried the suggestion but same result.

Comment: okay, to test your code you could provide your project through github.

Comment: The repo is [here](https://github.com/iSlayer/my_quick_example)

Comment: Why do you assume that the shift key is used to set the "Y" and not "y"?

Comment: I tested you question. When doing `keyClick("y", Qt.ShiftModifier)` output is `y`. And when trying `keyClick("Y", Qt.ShiftModifier)` output is `Y` with no change.

Comment: the shift key does not modify the letter :-)

Comment: My question is, why do **you** assume that with the SHIFT key it is going to be converted into capital letters? That does not make sense.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. It seems I need a different approach. I was using this as a simple test because I think I want to get more complicated by using the TAB modifier to change focus to the next text field to make sure they are in proper order. Is there another way to try to implement what I am looking for?

Comment: I do not understand you. Do you have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)? in your current question you want to test the SHITF key, which according to your test should convert to uppercase, but now you speak of the TAB key.

Comment: I didn't mean an XY problem. The Y part is a different stage and shouldn't have brought that up. I basically would like to implement keyclick() keypress() and keysequences() to set text fields without using `qmlObj.text = "Foo"`, I would prefer to use ui commands of the clicks and keys.

Comment: ut your first test is correct, you still do not answer me: **why do you think `keyClick(QT.Key_Y, Qt.ShiftModifier)` will write a "Y" in the text field?**

Comment: I guess I read the description incorrectly. The description just says: [keyClick](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qttest-testcase.html#keyClick-method)"Simulates clicking of `key` with an optional modifier on the currently focused item."

Comment: the documentation is correct. But **why do you think the combination: "shift + y" generates "Y"?** that does not indicate the docs.

Comment: I think this because when I type on a keyboard you hold the button combination of shift + y to get Y.

Comment: that conversion is done by the OS, not by what you point out is not correct in Qt. In Qt if you want to write in capital letters you must use keyPress ("Y"), the combination of keys is not fully supported as it often depends on each OS and but of each keyboard, there is no standard.